# My app crashed when open camera in Android 7.0

Tags: android

My app crashed when open camera in Android 7.0

```
        File captureFilePath = new File(cachePath, CommonUtil.getDateTimeForFileName(System.currentTimeMillis())+".jpg");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(captureFilePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        CAPTURE_IMAGE_PATH = captureFilePath.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242026/fileuriexposedexception-in-android-n-with-camera/48985553#48985553

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed you need to use file provider..

Comment: past your `manifest.xml` file

Comment: share your error log

Comment: If target version is >= 24 then you have to use FileProvider to get the URI.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your targetSdkVersion >= 24, then we have to use FileProvider class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps.

1) First Add a FileProvider tag in AndroidManifest.xml under tag as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.my.package.name.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2) Then create a provider_paths.xml file in res/xml folder. Folder may be needed to created if it doesn't exist.

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

3) Now edit your activity class file as below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(captureFilePath);
```

to

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, captureFilePath);
```

Comment: just add...

        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.tourinpay.android.tip.tipper.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

My app crashed before it runs.

Comment: @임정택 Are you able resolve this or not? as you marked this question as correct I assume that you are able to resolve your issue. Please let me know if you face any issue.